# Ошибки Uncaught TypeError: .equalize, .easing[jQuery.easing.def], .closest('.jqmWindow').jqmHide(), .ikSelect() при закрытии карточки товара. Битрикс

Tags: javascript, jquery, битрикс

Есть сайт (залит на битрикс) с каталогом товаров и возможностью открытия "карточки" данного товара (быстрый просмотр). Проблема состоит в том, что большинство (не все) карточек не закрываются при клике на "x", нажатие esc или клике на область вне карточки.
Простите сразу за такие глупые вопросы, я профан в этом.

Ошибки, которые вылезают при открытии данной карточки:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).equalize is not a function;

```
$('.set_block').ready(function(){
   $('.set_block ').equalize({children: '.item:not(".r") .cost', reset: true});
   $('.set_block').equalize({children: '.item .item-title', reset: true});
   $('.set_block').equalize({children: '.item .item_info', reset: false});
});
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined;

```
catch(e){
   console.error(e);
}
finally{
   // restore $.cookie option
   $.cookie.json = bCookieJson;
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function;

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{
    def: 'easeOutQuad',
    swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
        return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
    }, ...
```

Ошибки при попытке выйти из этой карточки:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).jqmHide is not a function;

```
$('.jqmClose').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.jqmWindow').jqmHide();
})
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqmHide is not a function;

```
 $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        if($('.jqmWindow').length){
            $('.jqmWindow').jqmHide();
        } ...
```

Мне кажется, что каким-то образом, имея какое-то условие, накрывается jquery.
Помогите/скажите в какую область копать. Т.к. всё на битриксе, то вдвойне сложней искать и просматривать файлы.

Чтобы всё просмотреть самому:
[сайт](https://www.kvadroavto.ru)

На главной странице снизу есть категории.

В хитах (открыты по стандарту) последние два товара при нажатии на "быстрый просмотр" открываются и благополучно закрываются, остальные - нет.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]
У вас сервер отдаёт `jquery` который переписывает переменную `$` тем самым убивая вся плагины.

Comment: И как возможно исправить данную ошибку ?

Comment: Я так понял, просто отрубить подключение jquery. т.к. в других карточках он не подключается, но теперь проблема стоит в том, где находятся файлы данных карточек